# Convert string dict type to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, annotations, yolov5

I am trying to convert a column of the data frame to dict using python.

The dataframe is of the form

```
filename        bbox-coordinates

image_name1     '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":161,""y"":562,""width"":51,""height"":96}'
image_name2     '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":151,""y"":542,""width"":32,""height"":69}'
image_name3     '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":140,""y"":42,""width"":30,""height"":45}'
```

the bbox-coordinate value is of type string and I am trying to convert it to dict.

```
dataframe['bbox-coordinate'][2]
output: '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":140,""y"":42,""width"":30,""height"":45}' which is string
```

Here:

```
 [1] type(dataframe['region_shape_attributes'][0])
output: str
```

I tried using:

```
ast.literal_eval --- doesn't work 
json.loads(dataframe['bbox-coordinate'][2]) 
output: JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
```

My ultimate goal is to convert the entire dataframe into YOLO format .txt with image class name, this has only one class i.e 0 and to extract the x, y, height and width in the YOLO .txt format for each file_name.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems like your strings have double double-quotes in them (`""`). Just replace them with single double-quotes (`"`) and `ast.literal_eval()` will work just fine.

```
from ast import literal_eval

strings = [
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":161,""y"":562,""width"":51,""height"":96}',
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":151,""y"":542,""width"":32,""height"":69}',
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":140,""y"":42,""width"":30,""height"":45}'
    ]

dicts = []
for s in strings:
    d = literal_eval(s.replace('""', '"'))
    dicts.append(d)

print(dicts)
```

returns

```
[{'name': 'rect', 'x': 161, 'y': 562, 'width': 51, 'height': 96}, 
 {'name': 'rect', 'x': 151, 'y': 542, 'width': 32, 'height': 69}, 
 {'name': 'rect', 'x': 140, 'y': 42, 'width': 30, 'height': 45}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the standard library json.

```
import json

strigDicts = [
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":161,""y"":562,""width"":51,""height"":96}',
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":151,""y"":542,""width"":32,""height"":69}',
    '{""name"":""rect"",""x"":140,""y"":42,""width"":30,""height"":45}'
    ]

dicts = []
for d in strigDicts:
    dicts.append(json.loads(d.replace('""', '"')))
```